# Разделить массив по правилу выражению

Tags: php, массивы, логика

может кто нибудь подсказать как лучше решить задачку ? Суть такова : есть массив [ 5, 5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 5 ] его нужно разделить на два массива так чтобы в первой части были числа которые не повторяются во второй, потом нужно найти индекс числа с которого будет начинаться второй массив (записав в переменную) и потом вставить перед этим числом разделитель | (вертикальная черта) в этот же массив чтобы на выходе получилось [ 5, 5, 1, 7, "|", 2, 3, 5 ].
каждый раз числа в массиве могут быть разными.
Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: непонятно почему именно так [ 5, 5, 1, 7, '|', 2, 3, 5 ], ведь под условие подойдет [ 5, 5, "|", 1, 7, 2, 3, 5 ] или даже не так.  Исходя из условия _в первой части были числа которые не повторяются во второй_ [1, 7, 2, 3, '|', 5, 5, 5]

Comment: Стоит привести точную формулировку, а не это: `нужно разделить на два массива так чтобы в первой части были числа которые не повторяются во второй,` и показать пример, соответствующий формулировке